# Understanding Eventual Consistency, BacklogItem and Tasks example from Vaughn Vernon

Tags: rabbitmq, domain-driven-design, domain-events

I'm struggling to understand how to implement Eventual Consistency with the exposed example of BacklogItems and Tasks from Vaughn Vernon. The statement I've understood so far is (considering the case where he splits BacklogItem and Task into separate aggregate roots):

> A BacklogItem can contain one or more tasks. When all remaining hours from a the tasks of a BacklogItem are 0, the status of the BacklogItem should change to "DONE"

I'm aware about the rule that says that you should not update two aggregate roots in the same transaction, and that you should accomplish that with eventual consistency.

Once a Domain Service updates the amount of hours of a Task, a `TaskRemainingHoursUpdated` event should be published to a `DomainEventPublisher` which lives in the same thread as the executing code. And here it is where I'm at a loss with the following questions:

- I suppose that there should be a subscriber (also living in the same thread I guess) that should react to `TaskRemainingHoursUpdated` events. At which point in your Desktop/Web application you perform this subscription to the Bus? At the very initialization of your app? In the application code? Is there any reasoning to place domain subscriptors in a specific place?
- Should that subscriptor (in the same thread) call a BacklogItem repository and perform the update? (But that would be a violation of the rule of not updating two aggregates in the same transaction since this would happen synchronously, right?).
- If you want to achieve eventual consistency to fulfil the previously mentioned rule, do I really need a Message Broker like RabbitMQ even though both BacklogItem and Task live inside the same Bounded Context?
- If I use this message broker, should I have a background thread or something that just consumes events from a RabbitMQ queue and then dispatches the event to update the product?

I'd appreciate if someone can shed some clear light over this since it is quite complex to picture in its completeness.

Comment: I don't remember how this is all introduced in Vernon's book, but distinguishing the essential complexity of the various approaches around DDD from the accidental, technical complexity of your tools is key. Greg Young has a zero-infrastructure simplified [implementation](https://github.com/gregoryyoung/m-r) of CQRS + event sourcing you might want to check out. Especially see the fake bus that operates entirely in-process, and how its methods are used.

Answer (score 2):

So to start with, you need to recognize that, if the `BacklogItem` is the authority for whether or not it is "Done", then it needs to have all of the information to compute that for itself.

So somewhere within the BacklogItem is data that is tracking which Tasks it knows about, and the known state of those tasks.  In other words, the `BacklogItem` has a *stale copy* of information about the task.

That's the "eventually consistent" bit; we're trying to arrange the system so that the cached copy of the data in the `BacklogItem` boundary includes the new changes to the task state.

That in turn means we need to send a *command* to the `BacklogItem` advising it of the changes to the task.

From the point of view of the backlog item, we don't really care where the command comes from.  We could, for example, make it a manual process "After you complete the task, click this button here to inform the backlog item".

But for the sanity of our users, we're more likely to arrange an event handler to be running: when you see the output from the task, forward it to the corresponding backlog item.

> At which point in your Desktop/Web application you perform this subscription to the Bus? At the very initialization of your app?

That seems pretty reasonable.

> Should that subscriptor (in the same thread) call a BacklogItem repository and perform the update? (But that would be a violation of the rule of not updating two aggregates in the same transaction since this would happen synchronously, right?).

Same thread and same transaction are not *necessarily* coincident.  It can all be coordinated in the same thread; but it probably makes more sense to let the consequences happen in the background.  At their core, events and commands are just messages - write the message, put it into an inbox, and let the next thread worry about processing.

> If you want to achieve eventual consistency to fulfil the previously mentioned rule, do I really need a Message Broker like RabbitMQ even though both BacklogItem and Task live inside the same Bounded Context?

No; the mechanics of the plumbing matter not at all.

Comment: I'm not fully grasping the "Same thread and same transaction are not necessarily coincident". What do you mean exactly? When you say "It can all be coordinated in the same thread" you are referring to process the event synchronously? And when you say "but it probably makes more sense to let the consequences happen in the background" you mean either starting a new thread to call the subscriber or relying on a messaging infrastructure? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidJiménezMartínez You need at least once/exactly one delivery guarantee here so any mechanism that will fulfill one of these premise will be fine. If you can't implement or have access to such mechanism then execute it in the same transaction, but decouple with events to show it could be eventually consistent. An easy implementation I've used is to use a database table as a processing queue where a single thread would dequeue and process events one at a time.